# The longest super tie break?

Tags: trivia, tennis, records, tie-breaker

What is the longest super tie break (10 points final set) in tennis history in official ATP and WTA matches?

Comment: [Longest Match Tiebreak](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=198802) at menstennisforums.
23-21 in the first round match of [2007 Estoril Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Estoril_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Doubles) is mentioned there. The players were  Montañés/Ramírez Hidalgo vs. Aspelin/Čermák.
This tie-break is also mentioned on [this website](http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records).

Comment: @Martin it would be good if you answer the question instead of writing it in comments section.

Comment: @suhas Martin's find only half of the reply: I was asking record for ATP and WTA matches. Maybe this is the way of "replying" in the comments and not as a complete reply

Comment: BTW the website I linked also has [WTA section](http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-wta-records).but they do not list hits particular record there. @suhas In addition to what Ale said, I am not sure to which extent the linked site can be considered a reliable source.

Comment: Here is an article from WTA site: http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/3771297 (Which I would consider official source.) The article is from 2014. It lists as a record first round match from [2008 Amelia Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Bausch_%26_Lomb_Championships_%E2%80%93_Doubles) between Mattek/Uhlířová and Craybas/Krajicek with super tie break 21-19.

Comment: Some relevant information can be probably also found in the Wikipedia article [Longest tiebreaker in tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_tiebreaker_in_tennis).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a specific statistic.

Comment: At the moment the post has two close votes. Personally, I think that questions like this are OK, (We had in the past many questions asking about records and trivia.) I voted to [leave open](http://sports.stackexchange.com/review/close/8564). (But his would be probably discussion for meta. In fact, there are some related questions on meta like [this one](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/583/sports-statistics-and-topicality) and [this one](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/23) and maybe also [this one](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/216).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Men

Wikipedia article [Longest tiebreaker in tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_tiebreaker_in_tennis#Men%27s_doubles) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Longest_tiebreaker_in_tennis&oldid=996924163#Men%27s_doubles)) lists 52 points (27-25) from the match between  Bury/Kowalczyk and Dasnières de Veigy/Gicquel in the first round of [2012 Marrakech challenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Morocco_Tennis_Tour_%E2%80%93_Marrakech_%E2%80%93_Doubles). However, this was at ATP Challenger Tour, not at ATP World Tour level.

The longest supertiebreak at an ATP tournament seems to be 44 points (23-21) from the match between Montañés/Ramírez Hidalgo and Aspelin/Čermák in the first round of [2007 Estoril Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Estoril_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Doubles).

Sources: [1](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=198802), [2](http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records) ([2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170706051124/https://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records)).

### Women

Wikipedia article [Longest tiebreaker in tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_tiebreaker_in_tennis#Women.27s_doubles) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Longest_tiebreaker_in_tennis&oldid=730042617#Women.27s_doubles)) lists as the record 42 points (22-20) from the first round match at [2006 Amelia Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Bausch_%26_Lomb_Championships_%E2%80%93_Doubles) between Pratt/Stewart and Morariu/Stubbs. The reference given in the Wikipedia article is [A Closer Look at the Longest Tie-Breaker in Tennis History; World Tennis Magazine](http://www.worldtennismagazine.com/archives/8769) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130113071447/http://www.worldtennismagazine.com/archives/8769)).

Another long super tie-break is mentioned in [this article](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/3771297) from WTA website ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/2*/http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/3771297)). It was 40 points (21-19) from the first round match at
[2008 Amelia Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Bausch_%26_Lomb_Championships_%E2%80%93_Doubles) between Mattek/Uhlířová and Craybas/Krajicek with super tie break .

Comment: I have made this post CW. Feel free to add further information. (What is the record for grand slams? Are there some official sources for ATP record? I did not find anything about this record on ATP website.)